# Как сделать, чтобы если в Text.Edit не было текста набранного пользователем, то вылезал messagebox?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtextedit, qmessagebox

Нужен `QMessageBox` который будет выскакивать если

```
def clicked(self):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        if self.textEdit.setText() == False:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание',
                'Введите все необходимые данные для расчетов.')
```

пока что это не работает.

Comment: попробуйте вот так: if self.textEdit.toPlainText() == "": если не поможет то, if self.textEdit.toPlainText() == None:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def clicked(self):
    text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
#    if self.textEdit.setText() == False:
    if not text:                                                   # <----
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            'Внимание',
            'Введите все необходимые данные для расчетов.'
        )
```